# Is it posible to use basic logic with CSS?

Tags: css

I've been working on some CSS for a chatroom to blur NSFW images until they're hovered over, and I got that working well. Now I'd like to expand on that to be able to have checkboxes to toggle either always displaying the images, or hiding them entirely. I know the CSS I'd have to do, but I'm not sure if there's a way to select another element entirely that isn't a child of the checkbox by using `:checked`.

For example, in what I'm sure is broken, unusable CSS:

```
.hide-nsfw:checked {
    img[src$="#nsfw"] {
        filter: unset;
    }
 }
```

And just to give a dummy layout, without any styling,

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="chat-messages">
        <div class="message-id-goeshere">
            <img src="http://someimage.com/image.jpg#nsfw" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="configuration">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hide-nsfw" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Pardon the terrible syntax. I could do it in JS, but I'd rather keep it in pure CSS if possible. No CSS extensions. Is there any possible way to do that? I know there are no CSS parent selectors as of CSS3, but is there a way to select another element entirely?

Comment: Short answer: no. *Cascading* stylesheet is named so such that styles cascade down the DOM, i.e. it is impossible to transverse up towards the parent, or to the previous element — in this scenario you are trying to achieve both. If your checkbox is the sibling of your image and it precedes it, you can use the immediate or general sibling selectors `+` or `~`. Otherwise, you are out of luck and have to use JS instead.

Comment: "*I know there are now CSS parent selectors as of CSS3,*" - no, no there aren't. Not even in (the fast profile of) CSS 4 Selectors module ([`:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) being the equivalent).

Comment: @DavidThomas My mistake. I meant to say I know there are *no* CSS parent selectors.

Comment: @MaryMelody How is that Fiddle relevant to the question?

Comment: @Terry for an example how does checkbox method work and it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: So, why not put the 'show nsfw' checkboxes at the beginning of the page, and then use a general sibling combinator? `.hide-nsfw:checked ~ * img[src$=#nsfq] { }` (this is probably a horribly expensive selector though). The checkbox(es) could be positioned absolutely wherever they need to be (so long as they appear in the DOM before the images (or their ancestors).

Comment: Oh, and these NSFW images; they'll still be loaded at work (which is possibly not going to be universally appreciated by the employer). Blurring is an improvement on the alternative, but I'm not sure it avoids the primary problem of NSFW while, basically, *at W*.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for the awesome feedback. That actually may work. The expense on the page is one of my main concerns. It's a heavily modified version of AJAX Chat, an open source PHP chat software that I've been hacking on with friends for years. However, when it has a heavy JS load, it seems to develop a terrible habit of eating messages. Doing it in CSS may help avoid that. Also, there are few NSFW images posted on there, but it's more of a utility feature that I planned on doing. The image loading isn't a problem, since it's rarely accessed at work, but sometimes, it's inopportune nsfw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS, you can control the styles of the following siblings of given element (those that come later in the source code in the same parent element). So you need to change your markup to enable CSS-only switching of the style. E.g. you can place the checkbox before the image and refer to it from the `label` element, like

HTML

```
...
        <input type="checkbox" class="hide-nsfw" id="hide-nsfw" />
        <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg" />

...
        <label for="hide-nsfw">Toggle Image</label>
```

CSS

```
.hide-nsfw {
    position: fixed;
    left: -99px; /* hide from screen, preserve availability for Tab */
}

.hide-nsfw ~ img { visibility: hidden; }
.hide-nsfw:checked ~ img { visibility: visible; }
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2hhrycbg/)

Keeping the controls before controlled elements in the same container, you can do even more complicated logic in CSS, like [in this example](http://kizu.ru/en/fun/filters/). But this approach is still more limited than the JS way.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, you'd need something called a parent selector for that, and they don't exist in CSS

> Find the div that contains a :checked box,
>   then all the images inside that div...

Your simplest bet would be to make the checkbox toggle a class on the highest parent you care about (something that contains all the images)

```
$('#myCheckBox').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('hideNSFW');
});
```

That code is using made up classes because you didn't post and markup, but you can get the drift from it and apply it to your HTML.

Comment: Sorry Terry; I didn't reload my editing page before I saved for the second time. Thanks for the formatting!

Comment: But it would probably be better to have it apply the classes to the objects they are used on, instead of some sudo global variable. `$('img').toggleClass('hideNSFW');` sort of thing.

Comment: Jonathon, I'd disagree; You'd be adding or removing potentially 100's of classes. Touching the DOM is very expensive, so what you're suggesting could get very slow. CSS parsing and repainting, however, is one of the most tuned parts of a browser, and is quite fast.